# VIM plugins Nerdtree and Source explorer have conflicts

Tags: vim, plugins, conflict

When the cursor reaches some files or directories in Nerdtree window with the Source explorer opening,the Nerdtree window will lose content.

[image]

if the cursor reach file init.S,the problem occurs:

[image]

Comment: I guess the Source Explorer updates another (previous?) window as part of its operation, right? As the NERDTree window looks like any regular Vim window, there's nothing preventing a plugin from trampling upon it. Either you can adapt your usage so that NERDTree never becomes the target (always go somewhere else first), or Source Explorer needs to be adapted to skip NERDTree (and other special) windows.

Comment: It seems that it is associated with this issue https://github.com/wesleyche/SrcExpl/issues/1

Comment: But I don't know about vim script and it doesn't show the usage that can disable updating other windows